# Best way to visually represent data

Tags: data-visualization

Given that i have the following data.

[image]

if i was to choose the best player based strictly on percentage of missed shots without knowing the total number of shots taken and total number of misses then i would pick player C OR D. However with the given data set i want to present this to someone in the best visual way possible to make them understand that look player A might have missed 13% of his shots but he took a LOT more shots than player C OR D. The best way to visually represent this i thought was using a stacked bar graph but is there better ways to graph or visually present this data?Also are there other statistical tests i should be doing? Appreciate all answers.

Comment: 1. remove inactive players (c,d,e,i).  2. Plot percentages of remaining players.

Comment: @vadim123 yeah i think, assume that we don't know who is active or inactive. I am sorry i should have mentioned all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a stacked bar graph with total shots on the y axis will do just fine. You can include the percentage of misses (or the percentage of hits) near the bar for each player. Your data are in Excel; it will draw the chart for you easily.

For this small number of players you are presenting all the data, so you don't need any fancy statistical tools.